# Replace ? with / in rewrite rules

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need to achieve this map given below :

```
https://www.domain1.com/open.html?cuSDyh&utm_medium=rep-email

to 

https://www.domain2.com/c/cuSDyh?utm_medium=rep-email
```

I write a rewrite rule to achieve this which seems wrong as "?" is not replaced in the end result.

```
RewriteRule ^/open.html?(.*)$ https://www.domain2.com/c/$1 [NC,R=301,L]
```

Can anyone help me to find the right rewrite rule for this one?

Comment: Which parts are variable in your URL? And the allowed characters in these variable parts?

Comment: domain1 will replace domain2, open.html will replace with c .first "?" with replace with "/" and first "&" will replace with "?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^/open.html?(.*)$ https://www.domain2.com/c/$1 [NC,R=301,L]
> ```

There are a couple of problems here that prevents the rule from working:

- The `RewriteRule` *pattern* (1st argument) matches against the URL-path only, which notably excludes the query string. To match the query string you need an additional *condition* (`RewriteCond` directive) and match against the `QUERY_STRING` server variable.
- The URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* does not start with a slash.

Note that the `RewriteRule` *pattern* is a regex. The unescaped `?` in the above regex is a special meta character (a *quantifier*) that makes the preceding token *optional*. So, in your example, the `l` is optional. (Although you match everytihng that follows anyway, so the `?` is entirely redundant.)

> ```
> FROM: /open.html?cuSDyh&utm_medium=rep-email
> TO:   /c/cuSDyh?utm_medium=rep-email
> ```

I'm assuming the first URL-parameter (eg. `cuSDyh` in your example) consists of letters only (lower or uppercase) and is not a name=value pair (as per your example). There can be 0 or more URL parameters that follow the first URL parameter.

Try the following instead:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([a-z]+)(?:&|$)(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^open\.html$ /c/%1?%2 [NE,R=302,L]
```

The `%1` and `%2` backreferences match the captured subgroups in the preceding *CondPattern*. ie. `%1` matches the first URL parameter (eg. `cuSDyh` in your example) and `%2` matches all subsequent URL params, excluding the delimiter.

The `NE` flag (not `NC`) is required on the `RewriteRule` directive to prevent the query string part of the URL being doubly URL-encoded in the redirect response. (The `QUERY_STRING` variable is already URL-encoded.)

If there are no additional URL parameters after the first then the above rule will essentially append an empty query string (denoted by the trailing `?`). However, the trailing `?` is removed automatically by Apache in the redirect response.

To avoid potential caching issues, always test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect and only change to a 301 (permanent) redirect - if that is the intention - once testing is complete.